# rpart package installation in R

Tags: r, rpart

I am trying to install **"rpart"** package in R. But I am getting the following error.

```
> install.packages('rpart')
Warning in install.packages("rpart") :
  argument 'lib' is missing: using '/home/sandeep/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.11'
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘rpart’ is not available
```

Can anyone please tell whats the error about? How to solve?

Comment: The problem got solved. Actually, in my system "rpart" package already installed. It will come by default through r-core. But its not showing anything when i am trying to install again. This may be the "bug". 

By loading package using library(rpart), I am able to use "rpart" function now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tip to start: If you're not sure whether you have a package already, you can use eg the function `find.package()` to check:

```
> find.package('rpart')
[1] "D:/R/library/rpart"
> find.package('lololool')
Error in find.package("lololool") : there is no package called 'lololool'
```

The problem is not so much that it is installed by default. It can be downloaded and installed from CRAN without problem using `install.packages('rpart')`, but if you check at the [package page on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/index.html), you see a very important line:

```
Depends:    R (≥ 2.13.0), graphics, stats, grDevices
```

which tells you that it is only available for R 2.13 and following versions. From your error, I deduce you still run 2.11. Quite some packages are not available for that old R version from CRAN any more, so you better update your R. Otherwise you'll run into this problem more often.

Be aware that if you run Debian, you'll have to do a bit more effort, as the default R in debian is always outdated. Just in case, you find the directions to do that [here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/).

Comment: you may also want to use `search()`to check what's already loaded.

Comment: @ran2: thx. Indeed, that's possible, but it won't show up installed packages if they're not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I found that once I restarted RStudio that I was able to install the package and find.package() showed I did, now, have the packages.